# Real time image stream from server to client

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, image, image-processing

I have large image 4k resolution on my web client (Angular application). Backend is .net.

I need some fast communication between server and client for live image updates.

Image below shows prototype of application screen.

Use case scenario:
User change some of the parameters (size, blur, rotation, some image processing ...), I send params  to the server server, server process image and provide new one which I need to display on the client. Image can be send from server in any format.

But I need high response rate, maybe 30 images per second.

It can be done with web sockets, that server sends new image every time, is there any better/faster (more optimized ) way for this ?
Is there some live image stream like video stream or something ?
Is it possible to do that with WebRTC ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The response rate you are searching seems to complicated. You can achieve a good file compression by using [WEBP](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/), but this will not be enough to accomplish it.

If you really need to upload it to a server and get data back like 30 images per second using 4k images, this will not work at all

Have you consider doing it all into client side? Is possible by using webgl, check this:
https://github.com/evanw/webgl-filter

Comment: This is initial requirement, we will try to achieve the highest frame rate we can if that is 15 or 10 images, we must be satisfied with this...  There is some special processing which can be done only on the back-end side, client processing cannot be used here. I do not know how live stream work, It can send 4k videos in real time, I need such approach.